# EditText not displaying keyboard on clicking

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a chatting application for Android. It has a list view to display chats, an EditText to enter text and button to send it. Whenever I click the edittext field, it does not display keyboard. I,ve tried adding `focusable` attribute to the edittext but it doesn't work. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="Type here" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="647dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ActivityMain.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
    RelativeLayout mainActivity;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.sign_out_menu)
        {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Snackbar.make(mainActivity,"Signed out successfully",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Snackbar.make(mainActivity,"Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                displayChatMessages();
            }
            else
            {
                Snackbar.make(mainActivity,"Login failed.",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton3);
        mainActivity = findViewById(R.id.main_activity);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new ChatMessage(
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                        editText.getText().toString()
                ));
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null)
        {
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        else
        {
            Snackbar.make(mainActivity,"Welcome back " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            displayChatMessages();
        }
    }


    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");
    FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(query,ChatMessage.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.list_item)
            .build();
    private void displayChatMessages()
    {
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.messages);
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull ChatMessage model, int position) {

                TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.username);
                TextView textView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
                TextView textView2 = v.findViewById(R.id.time);

                textView.setText(model.getUsername());
                textView1.setText(model.getMessageText());
                textView2.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",model.getTime()));
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** the TextInputLayout usually contains a TextInputEditText. That might be a problem there.

**Second:** something can be overlapping the EditText. Sadly I can't visualize your XML layout since it uses many fixed sizes. But the list is probably over the EditText.